# How to determine solution to following Integral solution to complementary Error function?

Tags: integration, error-function

I have following Integral, I want to determine its solution.

$$
\int_{\text{T0}}^T \frac{\text{erfc}\left(\sqrt{x}\right) \exp (x)}{\sqrt{A-x}} \, dx
$$
So far, I have tried Integration by parts by considering:

$$
u = \frac{\exp (x)}{\sqrt{A-x}}
$$
and 
$$
v = \text{erfc}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)
$$
But I couldn't converge to solution.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: *Welcome to the site !*. Have you any reason to think that there is a closed form ? I am quite skepical.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank for welcome. I saw some example here in this forum  regarding complementary error function. I can solve this function by numerical integration but I need an analytical solution for this integration.